# Can I generate, rather than source control .csproj and other Visual Studio files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

On the Java platform, the problem of pointless and irritating merge conflicts in so-called "project" files (often arising from meddling by the IDE rather than the developer) was definitively solved the best part of a decade ago. As soon as the technology existed to auto-generate from Maven POMs, the necessity to source control Intellij/Eclipse project files -- and all the associated annoyances and merge conflicts -- disappeared overnight (in my company, we probably have 40 - 50 apps, and not a single source controlled project file).

I'm vastly more familiar with the JVM platform than .NET, but all these years later, I'm amazed to have today heard a .NET development team complaining about the annoyance of merge conflicts in csproj and other Visual Studio files. Really? In 2016?

I'd love for someone to enlighten me: is this a solved problem in the .NET space, but perhaps word just hasn't filtered to this particular team? Any advice, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DStanley: He's not saying they don't use source control--he's saying they don't have any *project files* (equivalents of csproj files) in their source control.

Comment: And then Java developers have to deal with settings, configurations, target frameworks, build steps etc that are typically stored in project files. So these are stored in *different* files that *aren't* called project files but *still* need merging. PS: forgot bower, grunt files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I think the important differences are that these other files are typically managed by hand and don't try to explicitly declare every source file individually, whereas csproj files are generated automatically by Visual Studio and [often have three or four lines](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/04/16/csproj-merge-conflicts/) for every source file in the project.

Comment: According to [this article by Mary-Joe Foley](http://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-whats-inside-microsofts-private-preview-of-visual-studio-next/) projects without csproj files are coming in the next VS version which will be unveiled at Build2016. I'd like to see how the manage the non-trivial project settings. Just 1 more week

Comment: @StriplingWarrior *that's* not a problem. Moving the rows around is a problem (said in Crocodile Dundee, "that's not a knife" style). Imagine a 1000 line DTSX file where every save results in 500 changes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it is true that in Java world the same information exists elsewhere (e.g. POMs) which also need source-controlling, and can arise merge conflicts. But the point remains, that IDE-specific project files are generated locally from the POMs and NOT source-controlled. Therefore, the descriptor(s) that are source-controlled have zero coupling with the IDE, and thus the IDE can tinker and manipulate the project files to its hearts' content.

Comment: @user6105611 I'd be more concerned with that team's version control workflow. Merge conflicts in project files wouldn't be such a concern if they used small commits, short-lived branches and a workflow like gitflow. They would also be *less* of a concern with modularization, ie breaking big projects into smaller ones.

Comment: @user6105611 In fairness, the team weren't saying that it's a big problem. Just a niggle, more than anything. The team use short-lived local branches, but practice single branch development. In my opinion, complicated branching strategies such as Gitflow are looking evermore antiquated, due to their incompatibility with Continuous Delivery (which necessitates single branch development).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a rather large pain-point in .NET, largely because .csproj files (and specifically the way that Visual Studio auto-manages them for you) typically create an entry for each and every file in the project. (Wildcards are technically supported, but Visual Studio tends to automatically replace them with large lists of files.)

I have never seen nor heard of generated project files being used as a way to avoid this. I imagine there would be some difficult hurdles to overcome, because Visual Studio requires the whole project to be reloaded if anything besides Visual Studio itself changes the project file.

ASP.NET Core 1.0 will go a long way toward solving this problem with their "project.json" files, which favor glob-style patterns for defining what happens to different files in the project. However, as far as I can tell, this is an ASP.NET-specific piece, and most library projects will still use .csproj. (I may be wrong on this, and would love to hear the experiences of people more familiar with .NET Core.)

[Here's a feature you can vote for](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4512873-vs-ide-should-support-file-patterns-in-project-fil) to get this fixed.

Comment: Project-less projects are coming in vNext

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Can you elaborate on that? My understanding was that "vNext" has been renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0, which I already mentioned in my answer. Is that what you were talking about, or is there a non-ASP.NET component to that?